# Disable visual volume display on top left on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

How can i disable the visual volume overlay which appears at the top left on windows 10? It is very annoying if I change the volume then I have to wait 3-4 seconds till it dissapears, and I can't click anything which lays behind it during this time.

Is there a registry entry or something which I can set to false?

[image: Volume overlay]

Comment: The solution in the "duplicate" which is about (windows 8 btw..) does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have some co-workers who feel the same way, but we haven't been able to find a native solution that will eliminate the overlay.

A few of them have tried a freeware program called [Volume Step Adjuster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/volstep/) that does this, so it really depends about how much the overlay annoys you versus how much effort you want to devote towards hiding it.